# From the bivariate poisson to the Skellam (or Poisson Difference) distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, bivariate, skellam-distribution

I am looking at how to calculate the Skellam distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) from the bivariate poisson distribution.

I understand that the Skellam comes from looking at BivPoisson(X - Y = z) but I dont see how this can be seen starting from the bivariate poisson PMF.

Comment: The calculation is outlined at the Wikipedia article you link to -- [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution#Derivation)

Comment: Hi @Glen_b I've followed that and understand that ok.  I am interested in how you would see that from the Bivariate(X, Y) by enforcing Z = X - Y = z.

Comment: When you say "the" bivariate Poisson, which one are you talking about?  In the derivation there, they used independent Poissons which is what the Skellam is normally defined in terms of, and they use the bivariate distribution of those independent Poissons in the argument there (that's why there's the product inside the sum). The discussion at the link *does* also use Z=X-Y. It's not clear to me what you're seeking, exactly.

Comment: Specifically their expression $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty  \!p(k\!+\!n;\mu_1)p(n;\mu_2)$ does both, since the product expresses the bivariate distribution of $N_1$ and $N_2$, but $n$ is the dummy for $N_2$ and then  the pmf for $N_1$ in terms of $k+n$ and the limits both rely on $K=N_1-N_2$ directly). i.e. write $p(n_1).p(n_2)$ for the bivariate distribution, replace$ n_2$ by $n$ and $n_1$ by $k+n$ (because $K=N_1-N_2$), and fix up the lower limit (again because $K=N_1-N_2$ and the fact that Poissons are on $0,1,2,...$) and you have the RHS.

Answer (score 2):

This is to augment the comment from Glen_b.  While that gives the derivation in the case of the difference $X-Y$ of two independent Poisson variates, not necessarily with the same mean, the OP seems to ask for the case of a bivariate Poisson distribution.  I only want to point out that that do not make any difference for the answer!

The biviariate Poisson distribution is often defined as the distribution of 
$$
  (X+Z,Y+Z)
$$
where $X,Y, Z$ are independent Poisson random variables. (other definitions are possible). But then yhe difference is 
$$
    X+Z - (Y+Z) = X+Z -Y -Z = X-Y
$$
so the correlation do not play any role in the distribution of the difference.

Comment: I see that the Z 'coupling' term cancels.  But just curious how to derive that from the bivariate poisson.

Comment: Why do you need to do it the difficult way?

Comment: To ensure I understand whats going on and I'm curious - I still can't get the result that way which makes me suspect I'm missing something fundamental

Comment: In your example, things are ok since you're adding the same value to two Poisson distributions. But, when I have $X$ and $Y$, knowing whether they're correlated or not change things. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are 2 indepedent Poisson random variables with $\delta=10$. The probability of their difference (in absolute value) being 3 or more is $28.66\%$. Take instead the case where $X=Z+A$ and $Y=Z+B$, where Z is a Poisson (9) and A and B two Poisson (1) distributions. In that case, $X-Y=A-B$, i.e. the difference between two Poisson (1) variables, and the probability of it being 3 or more is $7.4\%$.